# Separable sobel filter implementation openCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on creating my own implementation of a separable sobel filter implementation. My function has as input the kernelSize, the horizontal filter of gradient Y as pixelsY1, the vertical filter of gradient Y as pixelsY2, the horizontal filter of gradient X as pixelsX1, the vertical filter of gradient X as pixelsX2.

The input of X1 is [1, 0, -1] (horizontal)

The input of X2 is [1, 2, 1] (vertical)

The input of Y1 is [1, 2, 1] (horizontal)

The input of Y2 is [1, 0 -1] (vertical)

```
void gradientFilter1D(Mat& img, int kernelSize, vector<double> pixelsY1, vector<double> pixelsY2, vector<double> pixelsX1, vector<double> pixelsX2)
{
    int sumMin = INT_MAX, sumMax = INT_MIN;
    //gradient X
    vector<vector<int>> pixelsX(img.rows, vector<int>(img.cols, 0));
    //gradient Y
    vector<vector<int>> pixelsY(img.rows, vector<int>(img.cols, 0));
    vector<vector<int>> sumArray(img.rows, vector<int>(img.cols, 0));

    for (int j = kernelSize / 2; j < img.rows - kernelSize / 2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = kernelSize / 2; i < img.cols - kernelSize / 2; i++)
        {
            double totalX = 0;
            double totalY = 0;
            //this is the horizontal multiplication
            for (int x = -kernelSize / 2; x <= kernelSize / 2; x++)
            {
                totalY += img.at<uchar>(j, i + x) * pixelsY1[x + (kernelSize / 2)];
                totalX += img.at<uchar>(j, i + x) * pixelsX1[x + (kernelSize / 2)];
                //cout << int(img.at<uchar>(j, i + x)) << " " << pixelsY1[x + (kernelSize / 2)] << endl;
            }
            pixelsX[j][i] = totalX;
            pixelsY[j][i] = totalY;     
        }
    }
    for (int j = kernelSize / 2; j < img.rows - kernelSize / 2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = kernelSize / 2; i < img.cols - kernelSize / 2; i++)
        {
            double totalX = 0;
            double totalY = 0;
            //this is the vertical multiplication
            for (int x = -kernelSize / 2; x <= kernelSize / 2; x++)
            {
                totalY += pixelsY[j + x][i] * pixelsY2[x + (kernelSize / 2)];
                totalX += pixelsX[j + x][i] * pixelsX2[x + (kernelSize / 2)];
                //cout << int(img.at<uchar>(j, i + x)) << " " << pixelsY1[x + (kernelSize / 2)] << endl;
            }
            pixelsX[j][i] = totalX;
            pixelsY[j][i] = totalY;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
        {
            int sum;
            sum = sqrt(pow(pixelsX[j][i], 2) + pow(pixelsY[j][i], 2));
            sumArray[j][i] = sum;
            sumMin = sumMin < sum ? sumMin : sum;
            sumMax = sumMax > sum ? sumMax : sum;
        }
    }
    //normalization
    for (int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
        {
            sumArray[j][i] = (sumArray[j][i] - sumMin) * ((255.0 - 0) / (sumMax - sumMin)) + 0;
            img.at<uchar>(j, i) = sumArray[j][i];
        }
}
```

Input Image:
 [image: Input Image]
Output Image:
[image: Output Image]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so my mistake was actually in this

```
for (int j = kernelSize / 2; j < img.rows - kernelSize / 2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = kernelSize / 2; i < img.cols - kernelSize / 2; i++)
        {
            double totalX = 0;
            double totalY = 0;
            //this is the vertical multiplication
            for (int x = -kernelSize / 2; x <= kernelSize / 2; x++)
            {
                totalY += pixelsY[j + x][i] * pixelsY2[x + (kernelSize / 2)];
                totalX += pixelsX[j + x][i] * pixelsX2[x + (kernelSize / 2)];
                //cout << int(img.at<uchar>(j, i + x)) << " " << pixelsY1[x + (kernelSize / 2)] << endl;
            }
            pixelsX[j][i] = totalX; <---- I overwrite the old values
            pixelsY[j][i] = totalY; <--- I overwrite the old values
        }
    }
```

So, pixelsX[j][i] = totalX and so forth is wrong, because I need the old values in order to finish the computation in the rest of the j, and i loops. So, I created another vector of vectors and pushed in it the totalX's and Y's, and this solved my issue.

Comment: Ah should have realized the Sobel isn't really like a 2D convolution. Same issue though, half the values in the vertical calculation were from the horizontal calculation and half were from the original image. Fix is to make them all from the original rather than my suggestion to take them all from the horizontal computation..

Answer (score 0):

The separable filter is computed in what are effectively two passes. (The passes can be interleaved, but all the values used by the vertical filter have to have already been computed by the horizontal filter if doing it in that order.) Right below the comment `//then here I do the vertical multiplication` there are accesses to pixelsX and pixelsY that are effectively a second pass of the separable filter. The values being accessed for negative values of x have been previously computed and the ones for positive values of x have not yet been computed by the horizontal pass.

check out [Halide](http://halide-lang.org). It makes this sort of code a lot easier and more performant. (A double nesting of std::vector is not a good way to go.)

Comment: Okay, so If I understand right, I pass over the image again, and do the vertical multiplication?